# wxpython: Multiple panels with wx.SashLayoutWindow

Tags: python, wxpython

Im Trying to create this:

```
|---------------------------------------------|
| Panel 1a |        Panel 2a        | Panel 3 |
|          |                        |         |
|          |                        |         |
|-----------------------------------|         |
| Panel 1b |        Panel 2b        |         |
|          |                        |         |
|---------------------------------------------|
```

So far I can only create this:

```
|---------------------------------------------|
| Panel 1a |        Panel 2a        | Panel 3 |
|          |                        |         |
|          |                        |         |
|---------------------------------------------|
```

How can I split panel 1a and Panel 2a in half? with a splitter?

My code is as follows:

```
import wx


class TestSashWindow(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        winids = []


        leftwin1 =  wx.SashLayoutWindow(self, -1, wx.DefaultPosition, (200, 30), wx.NO_BORDER|wx.SW_3D)
        leftwin1.SetDefaultSize((120, 1000))
        leftwin1.SetOrientation(wx.LAYOUT_VERTICAL)
        leftwin1.SetAlignment(wx.LAYOUT_RIGHT)
        leftwin1.SetSashVisible(wx.SASH_LEFT, True)



        self.leftWindow1 = leftwin1
        winids.append(leftwin1.GetId())
        self.remainingSpace = wx.Panel(self, -1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)


        leftwin2 = wx.SashLayoutWindow(self, -1, wx.DefaultPosition, (200, 30), wx.NO_BORDER|wx.SW_3D)
        leftwin2.SetDefaultSize((120, 1000))
        leftwin2.SetOrientation(wx.LAYOUT_VERTICAL)
        leftwin2.SetAlignment(wx.LAYOUT_LEFT)
        leftwin2.SetSashVisible(wx.SASH_RIGHT, True)

        self.leftWindow2 = leftwin2
        winids.append(leftwin2.GetId())
        self.remainingSpace = wx.Panel(self, -1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SASH_DRAGGED_RANGE, self.OnSashDrag,id=min(winids), id2=max(winids))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        slw = leftwin1

        x = wx.Notebook(slw, -1)
        for i in xrange(2):
            x.AddPage(wx.Panel(x, -1), str(i))

class mainframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, size=(400,300), title="sash test")

        self.a = TestSashWindow(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = wx.App(0)
    b = mainframe()
    b.Show(1)
    a.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generell concept of layout management are containers and widgets. In containers you can place other containers and widgets. To accomplish the given layout, you have to organize your containers and widgets in a hierarchy in a clever way. Since your supplied code is still incomplete, I'll won't provide you with a full solution, but rather answer your question how you can split both panels.

1. Create two panels, namely `panel1`, `panel2` and `panel3`. It seems you've gotten so far.
2. Set sizers on both (for instance a `BoxSizer`)
3. Create two panels, `panel1a` and `panel1b` with `panel1` as parent. Place widgets in these two panels as wanted.
4. Create two panels, `panel2a` and `panel2b` with `panel2` as parent. Place widgets in these two panels as wanted.
5. Done! For the desired layout, you don't necessarily need a `Splitter` (only if you wish to make them resizable. In that case, `panel1` and `panel2` are replaced by splitters. Read [this example](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/skeletons/) for details)

Visualization:

```
+ mainframe (horizontal layout)
|
+-panel1 (vertical layout)
| +-panel1a
| +-panel1b
|
+-panel2 (vertical layout)
| +panel2a
| +panel2b
|
+-panel3
```